# How to globally force node require to load different package then the original one

Tags: node.js

Let's say I'm using package A which depends on package B. In my code I'm only requiring A. How do I force A to load package C instead of package B?

The purpose for that is that sometimes if C is a fork of B, but is published under a different name, I want to force library A to use C instead of B.

Is there any npm package which helps with this and can be used on production without risk ?

Comment: It is kind of an anti-pattern in CJS. You may do it (I think) by tweaking the CJS engine in Node.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is widely used in unit tests for applications that do not use dependency injection, but use common js modules.

For example, you can use npm module [proxyquire](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwil6vrh4u3WAhUGxlQKHdCnDB4QFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.npmjs.com%2Fpackage%2Fproxyquire&usg=AOvVaw0V5l0aUUQvW0QfcoJV3Efb).

Sample:

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

const C = { 'hello': 'world' };
const A = proxyquire('A', { B: C });
```